# Is it a bad practice to push half done work to a repo?

Tags: git, git-flow

Today I've had a discussion with a colleague in which he's chastised me for pushing code which was breaking the app to a feature branch in our repository.

Essentially, I've been replacing a library which had widespread use in our application. This is a change taking quite a few hours of work over several days, so I split it up in several meaningful commits, but not all of them leave the application in a working state (e.g., there might be some broken unit tests or some compilation errors). I usually push every commit to the server as soon as I can to keep a backup.

What happened today is that a colleague merged my branch into the main branch by mistake and, unsurprisingly, the application didn't work for him. According to him, I should never push anything that breaks the app into the repo, even if it's in a feature branch; instead, I should only keep it in my computer until it's stable.

This goes against the practice followed in previous companies where I worked, so I'm coming to you for advice. Do you consider this to be a bad practice? If so, how would you handle a situation in which you're likely not to have a stable codebase for several days?

Comment: Merging by mistake and then blaming you does not sound like an appropriate process. The most important thing is for the team to establish what your process is going to be, and follow that. I personally agree with the discussion in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It ultimately depends on the workflow of your team what is allowed or not, however I would say it's very common that:

- **Feature branches are not at all times in a stable state**
  If they were, they would not be in development; or you would have to actively withhold changes to upstream repository.
- **Git is used as a backup**
  If you push your (incomplete) changes to a remote repository, you have your data backed up for free.
- **Feature branches are cleaned up**
  When branches end up too unorganized after a lot of development, it's possible to rewrite commits by combining (squashing) or splitting them, and then force-pushing (`git push --force-with-lease`) to the feature branch to overwrite the upstream copy.
- **There is a process for finalizing and merging feature branches**
  Usually called *pull request* or *merge request*, you as a developer of the feature branch **actively** promote your changes ready for review and potential inclusion in `master` branch.

Simply assuming your branch to be ready and merging it without test/review into master is rather careless. That is, until this is a workflow you explicitly agreed to -- but I wouldn't consider this industry best practice.

Some Git hosting platforms also allow to enforce that changes go through PR/MRs, and some even prohibit merging of branches adhering to a certain name scheme (e.g. containing "WIP" ).

Comment: good explanation.  But while it dependes on the teams workflow how to exactly handle the process and a developer should work in an team/environment,
it does NOT depend on the workflow of his team if this is "bad practice".
only because one time does crazy things the right doing never gets wrong. ;)

Answer (score 3):

No. As long as you don't merge your branch you can push everything. 
Some refactorings need processing by ci/cd for testing, etc.
Or you need to push in order to start a tool based review etc.

If you don't want a branch merged you could define a prefix for example  "WIP" and prevent merging such branches.

"Keeping everything on your computer still it works¨ will bring you to hell as soon as other developers develop on your project. When you get ill no-one can take over, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A "feature branch" may or may not be shared, so it's unclear what exactly you mean by that.

But basically, as long as the branch you push to is defined to be not shared with anyone, then you should be fine to push whatever you want (and usually it's even allowed to force-push to branches like that).

Answer (score 0):

You can push any changes you have made and publish to your remote branch. As long nobody is merging your branch, everybody is in safe side and you got your backup reserved. But for use cases(I follow),suppose you are working in a module/feature where the feature is not complete but you have pushed your changes to remote. Later you have another change/addition or completed your feature and now for some reason, you need to know what are the changes you have made in existing code. What you will do? You have to go through all your commits made for a single feature and it will be too much cumbersome if you have code snippets which was changed/edited multiple time.
But if you have only a single commit, you would be much easier to revise your changes and less time consuming.

Comment: i disagree. If you want a single commit you could squash those multiple commits on your feature-branch to a single one when mergeing back to master. 
If you don want this (because even the history within your feature branch is valuable) you don have to do this.

Throwing away information at a later point is always possible.
Not commiting for multiple days just to have a nicer looking history is no option...

Comment: you are right on your point but what I meant is  file changed in  multiple commits in a particular area  say for logical error or typo you will not get the whole change log i.e the full change big picture.

Comment: that true. therefor you can rewrite history with an ammend or an squash.